# How long should it take for Facebook to activate my get started Button in messenger for my bot?

Tags: facebook, curl, bots, botframework, messenger

I have submitted my curl request to facebook and recieved a "Success" result. Its been over 48 hours and it has still not populated the chat for messenger. how long should it take?

Comment: Check your access token. How did you get it ? 
I got similar issue. I didn't realize that i've been using wrong access token.

Comment: Hi bob. I got my token using in the developers.facebook.com dashboard.
The Token Generation in the messenger tab and it returns the access token.

Comment: You should use your page access token.

Comment: How do I obtain this?

Comment: Check this out: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/236572350142896/

Comment: Unfortunately. Still no success. I have the proper token as well. I used the graph explorer to obtain it.

Comment: Delete conversation.

Comment: You have to "restart" the conversation to see your Get Started Button.

Comment: I have. But even the get function returns empty

Comment: Thank you for helping me like this

Comment: I told you all the issues i had. I thought that might help you. You must discover your solution by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that is populates instantly. My method was incorrect originally. It is easier to use the Graph API Explorer that Facebook provides.

Answer (score 0):

It should happen immediately. **You must subscribe to `optin` events from FB to receive the payload.** Check in your FB app under Messenger that you have subscribed to this event.

Delete your chat thread and begin it again. Whenever you make changes to the Get Started payload, Greeting Message, or Persistent Menu it requires you to delete your chat thread in order to see the changes.

**If you have already done so** and are still not seeing changes, keep in mind that you cannot actually change the text of the button, only the payload that is sent to your bot when tapped. You must be subscribed to postback webhook events to receive this payload.

Comment: Hi Jon. 

For some reason it is not populating. I am subscribed to the postback webook and have also only attempet to add only the payload using something like "/GetStarted".

I have even used the code from the FB example and changed only the token.

Will it make a difference if my page is not public/published live?

Do you mind sending some kind of example please. It will be truly appreciated.

Comment: Are you subscribed to `optin` events from FB Messenger? Go to your messenger settings in your FB App and check to be sure, you won't receive the payload without it.

Comment: These are my selected events: 
messages, messaging_postbacks, messaging_optins, message_deliveries, messaging_account_linking